# NullPointerException in grails rendering plugin if HTML tag id is set

Tags: java, grails, pdf-generation, sax, xalan

I am using Grails rendering plugin/service to create PDF. PDF data can be previewed by the user in the browser (then he clicks "download" button and gets PDF). Some of the templates for PDF and for browser could be unified into the one template. So that it is only included from the main template, which is afterwards sent to a browser or to a rendering service.

Unfortunately there is a problem: I need to have ID attributes on some HTML tags (like `<tr>` or `<td>`, which are used in templates which are sent to the browser. But if there is an ID attribute on some HTML tag in the template which is sent to a rendering service, it fails with NullPointerException:

```
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.startElement(SAX2DOM.java:211)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.closeStartTag(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:204)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToSAXHandler.flushPending(ToSAXHandler.java:277)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.startElement(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:646)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:636)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:707)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:189)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:75)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:55)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:43)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:38)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:34)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:33)
    at MyController$_closure4$$ENw2Jz9v.doCall(MyController.groovy:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I've tried to debug SAX2DOM and found that the ID element is the one, which causes this exception. Have anybody experienced this problem before? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind sharing some example code?

Comment: @TylerRafferty, sorry I am not working on the project anymore and don't have the code.